# Test Promise Error in componentDidMount Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm having a problem testing what happens when a promise fails inside of `componentDidMount()` with jest.  Here is the relevant code:

```
//TEST FILE
it('should show an error message when ZipkinService is down', async () => {
    const getTraces = ZipkinService.getTraces.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject('FAIL'));
    const getTraceById = ZipkinService.getTraceById.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject('FAIL'));
    const tree = Enzyme.mount(
        <TraceListComponent value={''} />
    );
    await tree.instance().componentDidMount();
    console.log(tree.debug());
    expect(tree.state().error).toBe('FAIL');
});

//REACT COMPONENT
componentDidMount() {
    return this.refreshData(this.props.value);
}

public refreshData(value: string) {
    let self = this;
    if (value !== '') {
        return ZipkinService.getTraceById(value).then(function(trace) {
            self.setState({traceList: [trace], error: undefined});
        }).catch(function(errorMessage) {
            self.setState({traceList: [], error: errorMessage});
        });
    }
    else {
        return ZipkinService.getTraces().then(function(traces) {
            self.setState({traceList: traces, error: undefined});
        }).catch(function(errorMessage) {
            console.log("CATCH HERE");
            self.setState({traceList: [], error: errorMessage});
        });
    }
}
```

But the test always fails not matter what I can't figure out why.  The closest I could get was by putting the expect inside of `process.nextTick()` but that seems wrong. I noticed based on print statements, that it's because of the fact that the test occurs *before* the actual update to error.  So every time the test runs, it gets `undefined` before it gets updated.